# How to match paired closing bracket with regex

Tags: php, regex, vqmod

My current regex matches a function name and the variable name passed to the function [see here](https://regex101.com/r/aJ7kT2/1)

**Regex** - `(file_exists|is_file)\(([^)]+)`
**string** `if (is_file($file)){`
**Matches** `is_file` and `$file`

I would also like the regex to work with a string rather than just a variable name, This includes strings with multiple opening and closing brackets.

Here's an extreme example.

**Regex** - `(file_exists|is_file)\(????????)`
**string** `if (is_file(str_replace(array('olddir'), array('newdir'), strtolower($file))){`
**Matches** `is_file` and `str_replace(array('olddir'), array('newdir'), strtolower($file)`

Is there a way to match the next closing bracket, unless one has been opened?

I would like to get it working at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tG3cB3/1)

Comment: So, you need a regex for PHP? Note that there is no  `str_replace(array('olddir'), array('newdir'), strtolower($file)` inside `if (is_file(str_replace(array(), array(), strtolower($file))){`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  thanks, that was a last minute edit. i'm using vqmod which does a find and replace for php files.

Comment: What is the regex flavor then?

Comment: Looks like PHP: try [`'~(file_exists|is_file)(\(((?>[^()]++|(?2))*)\))~'`](https://regex101.com/r/eF9bK5/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that seams to work brilliantly. thanks you. please leave an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex with a subroutine call in PHP:

```
'~(file_exists|is_file)(\(((?>[^()]++|(?2))*)\))~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF9bK5/1)

The pattern matches:

- `(file_exists|is_file)` - one of the two alternatives
- `(\(((?>[^()]++|(?2))*)\))` - Group 1 matching paired nested `(...)` substrings, and `((?>[^()]++|(?2))*)` is Group 3 capturing the contents inside the outer paired `(...)`.

Thus, the results are:

- Group 1: `is_file`
- Group 2: `(str_replace(array(), array(), strtolower($file)))`
- Group 3: `str_replace(array(), array(), strtolower($file))`

Use Group 1 and 3.